# Material UI Fab Button stays under left split-pane

Tags: css, material-ui, splitpane

How can I make the **Fab button** totally visible? Left half of it is always under left pane. Tried to increase z-index, but didn't work.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/splitpane-k8nvi?file=/demo.tsx:2253-2621)

```
        <UpperPane>
          <Fab
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              left: "-25px",
              zIndex: 999
            }}
            color="primary"
            aria-label="add"
          >
            <AddIcon />
          </Fab>
        </UpperPane>
```

Comment: The problem is that Fab is in a different [stack context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) from the left panel. In this situation, z-index has no meaning outside `UpperPane` container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify CSS properties and it will work -

```
 style={{
          left: "-25px"
       }}

const UpperPane = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:fixed; // add this property
  background-color: yellow;
`;
```

[image]

Working sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/splitpane-rqenw?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: I want fab buton stays on the resizer, not totally on the right pane as in your suggestion

Comment: @killjoy I have updated my post.You can simply achieve it modifying one css property.

Comment: No problem.Glad it helped.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

That's the behaviour I want. Manged to create using mutation observer. If anyone has a better solution, perfectly welcome :)

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/splitpane-with-fab-on-resizer-k8nvi?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Please see my updated post.I simply updated one CSS property to achieve the desired result.